# dechex returning wrong color

Tags: php, colors

I have hex color stored as a decimal number in the database and I want to convert it back to hex with dechex() PHP command. It's working for all colors except one. Here's part of my code.

```
$color = '#'.dechex($crew->color);
```

If I set `$crew->color` to 2139062017 it returns normal hex value for that color, but if I set `$crew->color` to negative value then I get the wrong output. For example, if I set `$crew->color` to -9849601 my output looks like this #ffffffffff69b4ff (which is close to correct because output should be #ff69b4ff, I just get those extra "f" in the color string.

Any suggestions how can I get rid of those "f"s, or what should I do to fix dechex() command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's using 64 bit and when using 2's compliment (for negative numbers) you would get `ffffffffff69b4ff`.

The easiest way I can think of to limit this to a 32bit number is to just take the last 8 characters from the result (using `substr(, -8)` in this example)...

```
$color = '#'.substr(dechex($crew->color), -8);
```